# java command got hung on linux machine

Tags: java, linux, rhel6

I am trying to launch my applications over Tomcat 7 using the Java version 6u45. I was successfully using the browser on my servers till some period. I installed all this setup on a cloud VM.

For some maintenance activity, our cloud administrator had restart the the VM instance on which Tomcat applications and Java are running. But after restarting I found the java commands are hanging instead of showing their output.

I ran the below command as a test but it did not show the output for long time even.

```
[root@s4web2 ~]# java -version
```

After a long time, it is showing its version almost around 1 minute which ofcourse is not the expected one. I could not understand why it is taking too much time for running java commands on the linux machine.

Comment: To understand which java are you using you could execute `which java` and than `ls -s [output of the previous command]`... At least you can understand who is executing your command. Is it only java that is slow? Every java application is executed as a different instance, so they shouldn't interfere each other. You could try to execute a `top` to understand if there is some process that it's consuming all the resources.

Comment: It is not the matter of knowing java -version. All the commands related to java, keytool and few other commands like tar and so on are showing the output with almost 1 minute delay which usually shows immediately.

Comment: Have you try to execute `top` to see if there is some program that is consuming resources? `top -o cpu` or  `top -o mem` to order by cpu usage or memory.

Comment: I could see in the top command that scanner command started by user nails is taking too much of cpu and memory. Is it required or can I stop it? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: It seems the virus scan, you can wait or stop it, up to you. For more information and the list of commands you could check in here: [link](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB73316)